# Convert a dict of dict into a DataFrame

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I have a dict of dict like this:
`data = {'1':{'a':10, 'b':30}, '2':{'a':20, 'b':60}}`

And I want to convert it into this DataFrame:

```
               1                  2
'data'  {'a':10, 'b':30}     {'a':20, 'b':60}
```

but use pandas.DataFrame(data, index=['data'])

```
         1   2
data    NaN NaN
```

use pandas.DataFrame(data):

```
     1   2
a    10  20
b    30  60
```

So how to get a DataFrame that its value is a dict?

Comment: why do you need that? Why do you need dictionary for values ?

Comment: Note that this will make accessing your data and filtering problematic to the point of being unusable and pointless storing in a pandas df

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange thing to want to do but you have to convert the values to a list with a single data element which is your dict:

```
In [42]:
data = {'1':{'a':10, 'b':30}, '2':{'a':20, 'b':60}}
for key in data:
    data[key] = [data[key]]
pd.DataFrame(data, index=['data'])

Out[42]:
                       1                   2
data  {'a': 10, 'b': 30}  {'a': 20, 'b': 60}
```